# How to remove duplicate item form array of string objects with _underscoreJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, underscore.js

I have this table

```
[
    "PC",
    "PS3,Xbox 360,PC,PS4,Xbox One,Nintendo Switch",
    "PC,PS4,Xbox One,Nintendo Switch",
    "PS4,PC",
    "PS4,PS5,Xbox One,Nintendo Switch,PC",
    "PC,PS4,Xbox One",
    "PC,Android"
]
```

I want to remove duplicated item and get this result :

```
["PS3,Xbox 360,PC,PS4,Xbox One,Nintendo Switch, Android"]
```

I tried this with underscore js but it given empty array :

```
 data = _.chain(games)
        .groupBy('platforms')
        .map((value, key) => { return key })
        
    
    return data
```

json data : https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.3b82169327044c04b7207fa186aee85b&right=local.tiniqu

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to run a function against the array at the top of your question or against the JSON you linked to? Assuming you're working with the JSON, it'd be great if you could include that in the question itself instead of just linking to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.map` to groups arrays, `Array.flat` to marge arrays and `Set` to remove duplicate.

```js
let input1 = ["PC", "PS3,Xbox 360,PC,PS4,Xbox One,Nintendo Switch", "PC,PS4,Xbox One,Nintendo Switch", "PS4,PC", "PS4,PS5,Xbox One,Nintendo Switch,PC", "PC,PS4,Xbox One", "PC,Android"];
let input2 = { "data": [{ "userId": 8, "game": "League of legends", "playTime": 500, "genre": "MOBA", "platforms": ["PC"] }, { "userId": 7, "game": "World of warcraft", "playTime": 1500, "genre": "MMORPG", "platforms": ["PC"] }, { "userId": 88, "game": "Dark Souls", "playTime": 109, "genre": "Action RPG", "platforms": ["PS3", "Xbox 360", "PC", "PS4", "Xbox One", "Nintendo Switch"] }, { "userId": 88, "game": "The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt", "playTime": 9, "genre": "RPG", "platforms": ["PC", "PS4", "Xbox One", "Nintendo Switch"] }, { "userId": 1, "game": "The last of us 2", "playTime": 100, "genre": "FPS", "platforms": ["PS4", "PC"] }, { "userId": 7, "game": "Hitman 3", "playTime": 60, "genre": "Stealth", "platforms": ["PS4", "PS5", "Xbox One", "Nintendo Switch", "PC"] }, { "userId": 99, "game": "Minecraft", "playTime": 1002, "genre": "Sandbox", "platforms": ["PC"] }, { "userId": 7, "game": "Hearthstone", "playTime": 1000, "genre": "Card Game", "platforms": ["PC"] }, { "userId": 7, "game": "FIFA", "playTime": 2000, "genre": "Sport", "platforms": ["PC", "PS4", "Xbox One"] }, { "userId": 2, "game": "The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt", "playTime": 78, "genre": "RPG", "platforms": ["PC", "PS4", "Xbox One", "Nintendo Switch"] }, { "userId": 47, "game": "League of legends", "playTime": 850, "genre": "MOBA", "platforms": ["PC"] }, { "userId": 2, "game": "Among Us", "playTime": 5000, "genre": "Multiplayer", "platforms": ["PC", "Android"] }, { "userId": 2, "game": "Valorant", "playTime": 2000, "genre": "FPS", "platforms": ["PC"] }, { "userId": 9, "game": "Valorant", "playTime": 80, "genre": "FPS", "platforms": ["PC"] }, { "userId": 9, "game": "Dark Souls", "playTime": 109, "genre": "RPG", "platforms": ["PS3", "Xbox 360", "PC", "PS4", "Xbox One", "Nintendo Switch"] }, { "userId": 9, "game": "The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt", "playTime": 900, "genre": "RPG", "platforms": ["PC", "PS4", "Xbox One", "Nintendo Switch"] }, { "userId": 24, "game": "League of legends", "playTime": 300, "genre": "MOBA", "platforms": ["PC"] }, { "userId": 24, "game": "World of warcraft", "playTime": 800, "genre": "MMORPG", "platforms": ["PC"] }, { "userId": 54, "game": "Minecraft", "playTime": 231, "genre": "Sandbox", "platforms": ["PC"] }, { "userId": 7, "game": "Minecraft", "playTime": 777, "genre": "Sandbox", "platforms": ["PC"] }, { "userId": 7, "game": "Hitman 3", "playTime": 90, "genre": "Stealth", "platforms": ["PS4", "PS5", "Xbox One", "Nintendo Switch", "PC"] }] }

let removeDuplicate = (array, procedure) => [...new Set(array.map(procedure).flat())];

let result1 = removeDuplicate(input1, item => item.split(","));
let result2 = removeDuplicate(input2.data, ({ platforms }) => platforms);

console.log({ result1, result2 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = [
  'PC',
  'PS3,Xbox 360,PC,PS4,Xbox One,Nintendo Switch',
  'PC,PS4,Xbox One,Nintendo Switch',
  'PS4,PC',
  'PS4,PS5,Xbox One,Nintendo Switch,PC',
  'PC,PS4,Xbox One',
  'PC,Android'
];

const result = _.chain(a)
  .map(s => s.split(','))
  .flatten()
  .uniq()
  .value()
  .join(',');

console.log([result]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.1/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For better asymptotic performance, you can insert `.sort()` after the `.flatten()` and then do `.uniq(true)`. This does not preserve the order, though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the first thing to do is normalize you array like this...

```
const array = [
    "PC",
    "PS3,Xbox 360,PC,PS4,Xbox One,Nintendo Switch",
    "PC,PS4,Xbox One,Nintendo Switch",
    "PS4,PC",
    "PS4,PS5,Xbox One,Nintendo Switch,PC",
    "PC,PS4,Xbox One",
    "PC,Android"
]

let arrayNormalized = []

array.every(item => {
  const arrayFromItem = item.split(',')
  arrayNormalizad = [...arrayNormalizad, ...arrayFromItem]
})
```

After that, you can use a function uniq from _js

```
arrayNormalized = _.uniq(arrayNormalizad)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use underscore nor any functional array methods to accomplish this

```
Array.from(new Set(array.join(',').split(',')));
// ["PC", "PS3", "Xbox 360", "PS4", "Xbox One", "Nintendo Switch", "PS5", "Android"]
```

This code

1. joins all the lines using the `,` delimiter
2. then splits everything into an array of titles by `,`
3. placing everything under `Set` removed duplicates
4. `Array.from` moves the set data back into an Array